# deskbar-applet function for Ubuntu 12.10 non-unity?

Tags: 12.10, search, indexing

Is there any tool similar to Deskbar available for Ubuntu 12.10?

Using Unity, the file lens does the job, but I can't work with Unity, so I have to use another desktop environment (fallback version/xfce).

The workflow that I need is the typical deskbar one, ie., for opening a random file:
- using a keyboard shortcut globally available
- typing the first letters of the name
- having the default file already selected and executable with just enter
- having the other files selectable just with a simple arrow selection (and then just enter)

I've tried catfish, but it's relatively slow, and in order to find the files I have to click each time on "deep search".
I can't find beagle or tracker either.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Cardapio does the job exactly as requested.

Installation (package name 'cardapio)':
- package name: cardapio
- via PPA: add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa

Working:
- Any shortcut can be configured. Many backend sources are available, including recent documents and goole; the base file system search is backed by MetaTracker
- The workflow can be entirely keyboard-based and is very fast, but the interface is also usable with clarity with a mouse

General notes:
- As far as I know, this is the most convenient files indexes on Gnome interfaces, for example as a replacement for Deskbar. It has several frontends though, so it can be used on several environments (currently: awn, cinnamon, docky, gnome 2, gnome 3, mate)
- It's very fast - much faster than Dash on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I recommend editing this answer to provide more information about Cardapio, including how to install it, how to enable (and perhaps how to disable) it, the main ways it is similar to the Unity file lens and the main ways they differ, and perhaps a screenshot. If you were able to do that, this answer (and your question which it is answering) would become significantly more useful and accessible to the community.